# How to style successful input fields in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to use Bootstrap's has-success and has-failure classes with Thymeleaf.

So far I have

```
 <div th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('field')}? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'"></div>
```

This displays the failure style correctly, when the form is posted and the field is invalid.

However if I change the second part of the ternary to 'form-group has-success', then on the initial form GET request, then, of course, it styles it as a success, even though the form hasn't been posted yet.

My question: is there a way in Thymeleaf to handle the following

1. Displays a form without any styling on GET.
2. On POST apply has-error or has-success classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Thymeleaf as a hasAnyErrors function.

```
<div class="form-group row" 
     th:attrappend="class=${#fields.hasAnyErrors() 
     ? #fields.hasErrors('field') ? ' has-error' : ' has-success'
     : '' }">
```

This now works.

1. When the user GETs the form, hasAnyErrors is false, so the empty string is appended and the input and label receive the default style.
2. When the user POSTs the form, if there are any errors then the first part of the ternary is evaluated. This adds the has-error or has-success styles.

This was inspired by Roel Strolenberg's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to add attributes to your `Model` in the back-end for this. 
In you GET request, change nothing. In your POST request, add an attribute: ["hasErrors", true] if the form data you send via the post is incorrect, false otherwise.

Now in your html you can add the following:

```
<th:block th:if="${hasErrors != null}">
    <div th:class="${hasErrors ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group has success'"></div>
</th:block>
<th:block th:unless="${hasErrors != null}">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
</th:block>
```

You check if the hasErrors model attribute isn't null, if it is, it means you're in the GET method and you should display a simple form-group. If the hasErrors is not null, you can create the ternary expression based on the boolean value `hasErrors`. The `th:block` is non-html. You can replace it with a div, but then you neen an extra div just to check a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not going into GET/POST problem but I think that this can help you:**

New *th:errorclass* for adding CSS class to form fields in error

Until now, whenever we wanted to apply a specific CSS class to an input field in a form when there were errors for that field, we needed to use the th:class or th:classappend attributes.

In Thymeleaf 2.1, in order to simplify this structure, a new th:errorclass attribute processor has been introduced. This processor will read the name of the field from the name or th:field attribute in the same tag, and apply the specified class if such field has errors.

Note the 'error' literal is in fact a token, so no single quotes are really needed.

The result is much more concise. Note also that th:errorclass works like th:classappend, not th:class. So the specified class will in fact be appended to any existing ones.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#errcl

Comment: While this is appreciated, I want to apply the class to the div that encloses both the label and the input. Bootstrap will then style both. This makes errorclass unsuitable in this instance.